# Loading a modal in Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Is there a way you can reference a cshtml file in a javascript file. For example I have an Index.cshtml that displays a modal to sign up. I want to reference this modal in my javascript file to display when the page is loaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ` I want to reference this modal in my javascript file to display when the page is loaded.`You can use partial view and display it in the page without using js.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the content of views (or even razor pages if you are serving those directly) into an element (often a div) using jQuery like this:

```
$("#yourdiv").load("@Href("~/Controller/Action"))
```

or

```
$("#yourdiv").load("@Href("~/Path/to/file.cshtml"))
```

This will load the content of the view into the DOM element.